# How to convert Date from 2023-11-10 09:44:00.038860 to 2023-11-10T09:44:20.001+00:00 in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, simpledateformat, date-conversion

I am getting response from ELK and mapping it to an object using ObjectMapper and then return the response as JSON. The ELK response has a Date datatype field with the format **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS**. The ELK response retrieved is in UTC and I want the API JSON response to be in UTC as well. So no timezone conversion required.
I want the JSON payload to display the Date field in the format **2023-11-09T03:00:35.563+00:00**.  It tried to set @JsonFormat on the field but did not work.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
private Date timestamp;
```

I tried using multiple formats yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX or yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'. But throws the same exception.

Also tried the following ,

- to set the date format for the mapper.

```
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
mapper.setDateFormat(out);
```

- to convert using simple Date format.

```
SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
String dateIn = in.format(Obj.getTimestamp());
Date dateOut = out.parse(dateIn);
```

Am I using the correct format for **2023-11-09T03:00:35.563+00:00**?
The exception thrown is
*Exception thrown [Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2023-11-10 09:44:00.038860": expected format " yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"*
or unparseable date exception is thrown.
Thanks!

Comment: You should not use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. They cause [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api). Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: Why do the seconds change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## String manipulation

In your case, the simplest approach is mere string manipulation.

```
String input = "2023-11-10 09:44:00.038860" ;
String result = 
    input
    .replace( " " , "T" )
    .substring( 0 , 24 )
    .concat( "+00:00" )
;
```

Comment: nice answer, I just posted another question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class YourResponseObject {
    private Date yourDateField;

    // Getter method for the Date field
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
    public Date getYourDateField() {
        return yourDateField;
    }

    public void setYourDateField(Date yourDateField) {
        this.yourDateField = yourDateField;
    }
}
```